# Firebase: combine query and child event listener

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nativescript

I have a structure similar to this

```
{
  posts : {
    post1Key: {
      title : "First Post",
      comments : {
        comment1Key : {},
        comment2Key : {},
        comment3Key : {}
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

And I'm using the "child updated" events on the key "/posts/post1Key/comments" to listen for new comments.

How can I combine Firebase Query and the event listeners.

**Edit:** I know this is possible with Firebase, however, I'm using [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase)

Comment: Could you give more details on what is your goal? It is not crystal clear what you mean by "combine Firebase Query and the event listeners".

Comment: Firebase provides a couple of ways to read data from the server, one is to query another is to use events. Queries allow you to sort and filter, etc. these events don't - as much as I know. My question is how can I achieve sorting when I use events to fetch data from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As at the time of writing, this isn't possible using the nativescript-plugin-firebase. The workaround is to do the sorting/filtering in the eventHandler after you have received the data.

```
var onChildEvent = function(result) {
  //
  // Sort: result.value here
  //
};

// listen to changes in the /users path
firebase.addChildEventListener(onChildEvent, "/users").then(
  function(listenerWrapper) {
    var path = listenerWrapper.path;
    var listeners = listenerWrapper.listeners; // an Array of listeners added
    // you can store the wrapper somewhere to later call 'removeEventListeners'
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can very well combine a `Query` defined with an `orderBy...` method and a listener with the `on()` method: see detailed doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#on)

For example you could do something like

```
var query = db.ref('node1').orderByChild('firstName');

query.on('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
  dataSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    console.log(childKey);
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    console.log(childData); 
  });
});
```

Each time a new sub node is added under "node1" you will get the children list ordered by firstName

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry I left out a key part of my question, I've edited the question and added it.
I know this is possible with Firebase, however I'm using a firebase in a nativescript application via a plugin (nativescript-plugin-firebase) and that doesn't seem possible at all.

Comment: @DavidLartey Ok, I cannot help you then.... I was tempted to delete my answer, asit does not answer your question, but I think I will not, since it may help someone who is looking how to "combine query and child event listener" (your question title)